# Запуск метода WIndows Service из планировщика задач со входными параметрами

Tags: c#, windows, service, планировщик-задач

Добрый день.

У меня есть windiws service на с#, для которого в планировщике задач есть (как ни странно) задача раз в сутки выполнять определенное действие. Так вот мне надо чтобы это действие было реализовано как отдельный метод в windows service, и чтобы этот метод принимал входные параметры. Как лучше всего реализовать такой метод и передачу параметров в него, не используя при этом методы OnStart и OnStop. Наткнулся на метод OnCustomCommand, в который можно передать код события, но как вызвать данный метод например из cmd или планировщика не очень понятно. Сервисами занимаюсь совсем недавно, поиск инфы в гугле не привел к желаемому  результату. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Не совсем понятно зачем вам в такой схеме вин-сервис

Answer (score -1):

Самое простое:
Ваша служба слушает сеть на порту ХХХ и по приему сетевого сообщения выполняет нужную команду.
Написать простое приложение для отправки сетевой команды, которое Вы потом сможете спокойно запускать из планировщика.
Если с сетью не сталкивались, то ищите классы `System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener` и `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient` . Только учтите что в службе Вам нужен асинхронный прием соединений. Ознакомится можно здесь: http://round-angle-net.blogspot.ru/2010/09/tcpip-c.html